# Mamp Pro localhost:8888 Gets Redirected And Shows 'Site Can't Be Reached Error

Tags: wordpress, mamp, mamp-pro

I am completely baffled on what's going on...

When I click the WebStart button for the localhost from the Mamp Pro UI, it opens that just fine and I get the expected address of http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English.

If I manually enter an address like http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/ it also goes to the correct place.

But when I try to either remove the '/MAMP/?language=English' from the WebStart page, or try to manually type http://localhost:8888 it redirects to http://some-other-website:8888/. This happens no matter what directory I point the host to.

I had set up a host of that name previously, but this morning everything just went haywire to the point where I completely uninstalled MAMP Pro and MAMP, but this is still causing me problems. This is happening with both Wordpress and NON-Wordpress local sites.

Really starting to lose it because I can't get any work done. I'm trying to make a Wordpress theme and I've even tried doing a new install of the WP in a completely different folder but now no matter what I'm doing at the moment I just can't get this thing to work :((

Comment: We are not able to debug your problem unless you provide enough information. Show the contents of each possibly existing RewriteRules and vhost configuration (from .htaccess or Apache config) and also please make sure you set a `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` in wp-config.php of your Wordpress installations.

Comment: Right now, MAMP is supposed to be pointing to a folder with an index.php file with the word "Hey!" in it and it's still trying to redirect to the some-other-website:8888. So there's no .htaccess in it, nor any wordpress files. I'm not sure how to get to the vhost configuration info.

Comment: How do you know where MAMP is supposed to be pointing to without knowing the vhost configuration? The only thing you could do is search all files for `some-other-website` and make changes accordingly in the resulting file.

Comment: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2015/02/editing-your-httpdconf-file-in-mamp-pro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I feel like a boob. It turned out to be the **siteurl** and **home** values in the **wp_options** table of the Wordpress database were pointing to the existing values I'd set up, but I had changed the host name in Mamp Pro so the pages would initially open correctly but Worpress would then rewrite the URL and... well, OOPS! I finally found this out thanks to looking at Daniel W's advice. I also had to reset Chrome because it was holding onto it on the browser end too. Thanks for the help, Daniel!